# System restarting without warning

Tags: laptop, memory, shutdown, memtest86+

I was running Windows 7 and from time to time it shutdown with no reason. I was thinking that it might be my fault, because I was using an x86 OS on a Intel Core Duo system with 4GB RAM.

I just downloaded Ubuntu x64 in order to do some memory tests. The system is closing itself during the tests. Which can be the reason?  What can I do?

ps: It is a laptop

Comment: By closing do you mean shutting down? Erroring out? Please give a little more info.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes back up are you told that an error happened, or that the last shutdown was unexpeted?

Does the **system** event log show an event from the **eventlog** service saying *The previous system shutdown was unexpected*?

i assume it is really a bugcheck (i.e. *BSOD*), and rebooting before you can even see the bluescreen itself.

Check that the option to automatically reboot is not checked in the advanced system options:

[image]

And check the Solutions center, to see if Windows recognizes that there was, in fact, a problem, and what the suggested solution is.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's overheating and shutting down.  This is pretty common with notebooks (laptops).

Get yourself a can of [compressed air](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CXWMRI) from on-line, or just about any office supply store, and blow out any dust or debris from the intake and exhaust vents and see if that helps any.

If that doesn't help, you'll want to ensure the fan is actually spinning (you should be able to hear it at boot, and feel air coming out the exhaust vent).  If it's not, then you'll probably have to take it in for service.

HTH.